What is the purpose of Hamilton Jacobi Bellman Equations?
I am trying to understand Hamilton Jacobi Bellman Equation and am stuck at a couple of places. I got this article from here. On page 255, the article states, "Dynamic programming suggests that we should consider the cost-to-go at each $t \in [t0, t1]$" The author considers an interval here from $t$ to $t1$. But what about $t0$ to $t$?".
In addition to this question, I have a couple of meta-questions that will help me better understand the process. What is the use of the HJB equation? The notes say, "It is the differential analogue of the principle of optimality.". Why do we need the differential analogue? Also, this process seems a little counterintuituve to me.
When I started learning Reinforcement Learning, I learned about value functions first and then learned about how we can use Bellman equations to compute value functions. Also, since solving Bellman equations using a matrix inverse took O(n^3) time, we used Dynamic Programming (DP). However, it seems here that we are starting with a DP problem and then applying HJB to it.


Let $t=t_0$, what do you get? 2. The differential analogue is much simpler to solve since it turns an infinite dimensional optimization problem where the decision variable is a function $u:[t,T]\mapsto U$ into a finite dimensional one where the decision variable is now a point in $U$. Regarding counterintuitivity, you will need to explain why this is the case. In the end, the differential version is just a local version of the Principle of Optimality of Proposition 6.11 (under some extra regularity assumptions). I recommend to accept that for now, this will certainly become clearer later.

